# Replace All Occurrences of Value in One Cell with the Value of Another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change names across multiple spreadsheets.  What I would like to do is change any occurrence of a string (which is the value of cell A1) with the value in A2.  Example below.  Changed cells are highlighted for ease of seeing what was modified.  I don't actually need them to be highlighted, however.

Before Search

[image: Before Search]

After Search

[image: After Search]

I understand how to use textfinder to  evaluate a particular text.  I do not know how to use it to compare the value of one cell with another.

I thought maybe something like this would work,

```
      function myFunction() {
  var to_replace = 'A2';
  var replace_with = 'A1'; 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ranges = ['C1:D' + lastRow];
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().forEach(r => 
    r.createTextFinder(to_replace).matchEntireCell(false).replaceAllWith(replace_with)
  );
}
```

but it only replaces the occurrences of "A2" with "A1", not the value of cell A2 with the value of cell A1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  It also does not replace "A2" if "A2" is only part of the string in a cell.

Comment: Hi there, is there any reason you do not use the "Find and replace" feature of google sheets? Ctrl + F and then click on the 3 dots on the textbox that pops up on the top right.

Comment: I would like to use this for multiple spreadsheets at the same time.  If an employee wants to change his name in the main database, this script can be run to find all instances of the original name and replace them with the new name.   Otherwise, "Find and Replace" would have to be run on each individual spreadsheet with each modification to the name database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the value of cell "A1" from the values of cells "C1:D".
- You want to replace the value of cell "A1" with the value of cell "A2".
- In this case, for example, when the values of "A1" and "A2" are "sample" and "test", respectively, and, one of the values of "C1:D" is "### sample ###", you want "### test ###"  from "### sample ###" as the result value.

Unfortunately, I cannot know the cell coordinates from your showing image. So, in this answer, it supposes that the cell of "Vanburen" is the cell "A1".

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the values of "A1" and "A2" are directly used. In this case, the cell values are not used.
- In your question, it seems that you want to use the value of cell "A1" as the search value. And, you want to use the value of cell "A2" as the replacement text. But, in your script, I thought that it might be in the opposite direction.

I thought that these are the reason for your current issue. When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var [[searchText], [replaceText]] = sheet.getRange("A1:A2").getDisplayValues();
  sheet
    .getRange("C1:D" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .replaceAllWith(replaceText);
}
```

- When this script is run, for example, when the values of "A1" and "A2" are "sample" and "test", respectively, and, one of the values of "C1:D" is "### sample ###", you want "### test ###" as the result value.
- When you want to replace "### sample ###" to "test", please test the following script.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var [[searchText], [replaceText]] = sheet.getRange("A1:A2").getDisplayValues();
    sheet
      .getRange("C1:D" + sheet.getLastRow())
      .createTextFinder(`^.*${searchText}.*$`)
      .useRegularExpression(true)
      .replaceAllWith(replaceText);
  }
  ```

#### Note:

- If you want to replace the search text and the replace text, please modify `[[searchText], [replaceText]]` to `[[replaceText], [searchText]]`.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: @Tainake, I will test this out shortly.  Thank you.

Comment: As regards cell coordinates you are correct.  The cell values do change when I run the script.  However, instead of Martin Van Buren as desired, the cell value is now Van Buren.  I wish to replace just the string within the cell that matches the value of A2.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are concatenated cells that include names as only part of the string within the cell.  I don't want to go back and develop a workaround on all that as for all intents and purposes all the other things going on in the spreadsheets are functioning properly.  A name change throws everything off, however.

Comment: @ScriptingNovice Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your actual goal? By the way, I proposed 2 patterns. In your reply, which pattern did you say about?

Comment: I used the second script.  Martin Vanburen became Van Buren.  It was desired that Martin Vanburen changed to Martin Van Buren.  In other words, search the sheet for the string Vanburen (as indicated by cell A1) and replace any found strings, not the entire cell value, with Van Buren (as indicated in cell A2).

Comment: @ScriptingNovice Thank you for replying. From `I used the second script.`, if you want to convert like `"### sample ###"` to `"### test ###"`, please test my 1st script. The reason that I proposed 2 scripts is due to my poor English skill. Because, from your question, I couldn't understand which you want to convert `"### sample ###"` to `"### test ###"` or `"### sample ###"` to `"test"`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Will try that this morning.  Thank you.

Comment: Excellent!  I misunderstood the original script description.  This does exactly what is needed.  I greatly appreciate it.  Learning how to write some of these more obscure (to me, anyway) functions can be quite challenging.